# Set clippath with path

Tags: html, svg

I'm following the examples on the MDN Web Docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) to set clipPaths. Unfortunately, their [last example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#Complete_example) for paths fails to work on firefox 68.0.1 and chrome 77.0.3860.5.

Is there a way to set clipPath with a path? I'm trying to clip an image with a path of a blob.

Comment: as per the MDN page, enable the layout.css.clip-path-path.enabled flag

Comment: Okay, it worked in FF, but seems like [it's still not implemented in chrome yet?](https://twitter.com/estellevw/status/1040252930060824577).

Comment: Since users need to explicitly enable this feature, are there alternatives for clipping with paths?

Comment: All alternatives are also listed on that page.